# on what http status codes are ajax failure/error callbacks called?

Tags: ajax, callback

for a standard ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.nodomainajaxcallhere.fail/busted.nogo',
      error: ----,
      failure: ----,
...
})
```

I thought that any respond with status code 200 is success and all other are automatically failure. But today I first saw "error" callback.

> when is the failure callback called?  on a connection error? 
>   when is the error callback called? on any other exception? http status code
>   400 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about JQuery, then none of the documentation for `jQuery.ajax` refers to a "failure" callback.  They only talk about "error".  I suspect this is either an anachronism, or someone was confused as to what the antonym of "success" was in this case.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: From the docs: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.